# AWS Cogntio Authentication with Postman

Tags: amazon-web-services, postman, amazon-cognito

Can someone explain to be how to authenticate with a user pool using Postman? I've searched for auth endpoints in the documentation, but I haven't found any references.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you are SOL with this. Part of this reason is because authentication with Cognito is highly customizable and therefor fairly application specific. For example you might be using federation with Facebook, Google, Amazon or SAML. You might be be using MFA or some type of custom challenge. If you aren't using federation, Cognito uses [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol) by default which means the client side does a bunch of calculations and black magic to make sure that you are securely authenticated without ever sending your password over the wire. Postman isn't going to know how to do this for you and you aren't going to want to do it yourself just for the sake of using Postman.

My suggestion would be to create a simple app that authenticates using the AWS SDK or even better, [AWS Amplify](https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify). You can print the auth tokens to the screen and just copy them into Postman to make authenticated requests to your API.